# How to pause for each plot when running R function

Tags: r

First, you need `effects` and `lme4` packages to run the scripts below with

```
library(effects)
library(lme4)
```

I have following script

```
 devAskNewPage(ask=TRUE)

 fm8 <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + Days + (1 + Days|Subject), sleepstudy,
          REML = 0, verbose = TRUE)
 plot(effect("Day",fm8))
 qqmath(ranef(fm8))
```

If I run the script manually, R asks `Click or ENTER for next page` after each graph. But when I run following function,

```
somefunc<-function () 
{
 devAskNewPage(ask=TRUE)
 fm8 <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + Days + (1 + Days|Subject), sleepstudy,
          REML = 0, verbose = TRUE)
 plot(effect("Day",fm8))
 qqmath(ranef(fm8))

}
```

R only asks `Click or ENTER for next page` for the last plot. How can I make it ask for each plot in the function?

Comment: Do they have to be displayed in sequence, or would you accept placing them next to each other on the same device?

Comment: @joran a good point. Either way is fine to me. I would like to know why devAskNewPage is not working though.

Comment: I think this *might* be a rather subtle example of http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f ; `plot(effect(...))` calls `xyplot`.  Try putting a `print()` around the `plot(effect(...))` statement?

Comment: @BenBolker You're right! (See my answer...) I find that a little surprising...ok...now that I thought about it for a sec it makes sense now. :)

Comment: Side notes: personally I'd prefer to open new devices for the plots. That way I can jump back and forth more easily by putting them side by side. If you happen to use RStudio, you can click through previous plots, so no need to ask wait for user input for producing the next plot.

Comment: @cbeleites Thanks for the info. I agree that we should be able to navigate previous plots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If plotting them together is acceptable, you might try this:

```
library(gridExtra)
somefunc<-function () 
{
 fm8 <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + Days + (1 + Days|Subject), sleepstudy,
          REML = 0, verbose = TRUE)
 p1 <- plot(effect("Day",fm8))
 p2 <- qqmath(ranef(fm8))$Subject
 class(p1) <- 'trellis'
 grid.arrange(p1,p2,nrow = 2)
}
```

The **effects** package messes with the class of the resulting plot, the confuses `grid.arrange`, so I had to change it back. I feel like `grid.arrange` ought to be more clever about that.

I can only speculate as to what's going wrong with `devAskNewPage`. The `effect` plotting code is pretty elaborate. It's quite possible that it is manipulating the graphics device in a way that overrides that setting.

**Edit**

I'm a bit surprised, but Ben Bolker's comment is right (i.e. this is a version/example of [R FAQ 7.22](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f), "Why do lattice/trellis graphics not work?", because the `effects` package calls `lattice::xyplot` internally). This works as the OP's asked:

```
somefunc<-function () 
{
 devAskNewPage(ask=TRUE)
 fm8 <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + Days + (1 + Days|Subject), sleepstudy,
          REML = 0, verbose = TRUE)
 p1 <- plot(effect("Day",fm8))
 p2 <- qqmath(ranef(fm8))$Subject
 print(p1)
 print(p2)
}
```